# regex для выявления ФИО

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как доработать данный regex, чтобы он правильно выделял выделял ФИО написанное в формате "Фамилия Имя Отчество" и "ФАМИЛИЯ ИМЯ ОТЧЕСТВО"

```
[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+\s+[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+\s+[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+
```

Примеры ошибок моего regex

```
Перерасход Белокопытов Валерия Станиславовна ДО Алдан -> выделяет "Перерасход Белокопытов Валерия"
Залог Князев Серапеон Юрьевич -> выделяет "Залог Князев Серапеон"
```

Т.е. нужно чтобы регулярное выражение не читало первое слово в предложении, т.к. оно никогда не является Фамилией.

Примеры можно проверить на сайте https://regex101.com/

Comment: если пропустить первое слово надо то в начала  `.+?\s` добавьте. и регистрозависимость флагами регулируются

Comment: Чего нить такое можно посмотреть: https://regex101.com/r/TdWYQR/1 `^[А-яЁё]+\s\K(?:[A-ЯЁ][а-яё]+\s??){3}`

Comment: В РФ по закону человек может не иметь отчества. А если попадутся иностранцы, то вообще пиши пропало. Вот интересная статься об именах https://habr.com/ru/post/146901/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если гарантируется, что будет только одно слово перед ФИО, а сами ФИО будут полными, то достаточно немного дополнить ваше выражение вначале `(?!^[\S]+\s)[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+\s+[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+\s+[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+`. Конструкция впереди исключает первое слово в искомой строке.

**UPD**: Для учета двойных фамилий подойдет `(?!^[\S]+\s)([А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+[\-])?[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+\s+[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+\s+[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]+`

Comment: [Двойные](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) фамилии могут содержать дефис.

Comment: @Vadik, спасибо за напоминание, дополнил ответ